# Projection on a special polydedron

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, projection

Let $x_0 \in \mathbb R^n$ and $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n} $ is lower triangular matrix with all element being $1$:

$$
   A= \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
    1 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    1 & 1 & \cdots &1\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Define set $C$ as: $S=\{ x \in \mathbb R^n: b_{min} \leq Ax \leq b_{max} \}$, where $b_{min}$ and $b_{max}$ are vectors that have identical element:

$$
   b_{min}= \begin{bmatrix} 
    x_{min} \\
    x_{min} \\
    \vdots \\
    x_{min} \\
    \end{bmatrix},
   b_{max}= \begin{bmatrix} 
    x_{max} \\
    x_{max} \\
    \vdots \\
    x_{max} \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

I want to calculate the projection of $x_0$ on $S$. I'm wondering if there is any efficient way to do this, since $A$ clearly has a special structure. I've been trying to derive a closed form expression but no luck so far. Any idea would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Express $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ as $(y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n)$.  A naive conjecture is:
$$P(y_i)=\min\left(\max\left(y_i,x_\min-\sum_{j=1}^{i-1} P(y_j)\right),x_\max-\sum_{j=1}^{i-1} P(y_j)\right).$$ This is correct for $n=1$ and always yields a point in the polyhedron but fails to be the closest point even for $n=2$ if $y_1 \in [x_\min, x_\max]$ but $y_2 \not\in [x_\min-y_1, x_\max-y_1]$.